Removing black edges from Android app icon?
Here's how my native app's icon looks like vs a PWA on a Pixel 8:

I don't know why there are black edges for the native app's icon. My icons have transparent backgrounds, so it didn't come from the image file:

It looks like maybe the icon image is too small, so Android is filling in the extra space with black. I generated the icons using a popular tool (https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-assets), so they should be the standard sizes.
How can I remove the black edges?

A workaround is to manually change the inset values within
android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml

and
android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml

from 16.7% to 16.6%.
For example:
    <inset android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground" android:inset="16.6%" />

More details can be found at the logged Github issue here:
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-assets/issues/522
